# does fluent nhibernate support lazy loading of properties

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a person class with a photo property and i want to load just that one property in a lazy fashion. i see that [regular nhibernate supports it here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx). is this possible in fluent nhibernate to use this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just add `.Lazy()` to the Fluent mapping.

Comment: i dont see that property in the mapping.  i do see .LazyLoad()